# How to solve this 2nd homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this equation :

$$
x’’(y) + \frac 12 x’(y)^2 = \frac 32 y e^{-2x(y)}  \tag{1} 
$$

**My trial:**

- Let $x=\log r$, then $(1)$ becomes

$$
r r’’ -\left(r’\right)^2 = \frac 32 y 
$$

Then I  let $u= r’$, then $u’=r’’= r’ \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dr}$, but this gives:

$$
r u \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dr} = \frac{u^2}{2} +  \frac 32 y 
$$

I think now $(1)$ is more complicated cause we have many variables. So any help to find a simple solution for $x(y)$?

Comment: After the transformation $x = \log r$ we have $r \cdot r''-(r')^2-\frac 32y=0$

Comment: And it is doubtless that the coefficients are $1/2$ and $-2$? // The trick to substitute $r'(y)=u(r(y))$ only works if the original equation is autonomous.

Comment: This solution works well if there is no `y` term. But now there is `y` where `x` is a function of `y` , so the DE still homogenous  I think.

Comment: @Cesareo correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't the substitution $x=\log(r)$ bring the equation to $2rr''-(r')^2=3yr^{2(1-y)}$?

Comment: Almost you are right. It gives $2r r''-r'^2-3y=0$.

Comment: @Cesareo I see, in a past edit the RHS was $\frac32 ye^{-2xy}$, hence my confusion.

Comment: Reduction to the first order: Taking $x=2\log(z)$ we have that 
\begin{align}
z''=\frac32 yz^{-3}.
\end{align}
Now taking $z=-2y^{3/4}\xi(\tau)$, $\log(y)=\tau$, and $\xi'_\tau=-u(\xi)/2$ we arrive at an Abel Equation of the Second kind in normal form
\begin{align}
uu'_\xi-u=\frac34\xi+\frac38\xi^{-3}.
\end{align}
I see no solutions in the Handbook of Exact Solutions for Ordinary Differential Equations I'm afraid.

Comment: @EliBartlett correct is $\begin{align} z''=\frac{3}{4} y\cdot z^{-3} \end{align}$